# Properly assign img src with {{ route(function) }} and parameters using laravel and blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I got a question using laravel, I am trying to call a function and passing some parameters along with it using the {{ route }} method something along these lines here:

```
<img src="{{route('cacheImage', ['general', 'mini-logo.png']) }}" />
```

My route in my web.php file looks like this:

```
Route::get('/cache/images', ['uses'=>'HomeController@cache_image','as'=>'cacheImage']);
```

As a result, I am getting something like this here when the page loads in my img src:

```
http://localhost:8000/cache/images?general&mini-logo.png
```

But this is not what I want, what I would like is to have something along these lines here in my img src:

http://localhost:8000/cache/images/general/mini-logo.png

At the same time I want to call the cacheImage function in my controller and pass it both parameters, which are "general", and "mini-logo.png"

How do I achieve this? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: If you had it, say, something like this: `/cache/images/{arg1]/{arg2}`, then it would be possible. But the way you're doing it, it's a get request. If you're always going to have at least 2 arguments, then yes, it's possible.

Comment: Well, I might actually have several folders and subfolders, how would I be able to address all of them in one get route? Like for example cache/images/folder1/folder2/image and then cache/images/folder1/image or even cache/images/image??

Comment: You could have several dynamic arguments passed to it, but that gets messy. Instead, I think it's best that you just use the `get` parameters. That makes the most sense. There's nothing wrong with it at all.

Comment: Ok, so you'd say I should create several get routes with different parameters, when I need to follow a different folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your route to this.

```
Route::get('/cache/images/{type}/{name}', [
    'uses' => 'HomeController@cache_image',
    'as' => 'cacheImage'
]);
```

Controller method to this to be able to receive the url segments as parameters.

```
public function cache_image($type, $name)
{
    dd($type, $name);
}
```

Then you can generate links like so.

```
$link = route('cacheImage', ['general', 'mini-logo.png']);
// generates http://example.dev/cache/images/general/mini-logo.png
```

Comment: This works great, how do I make it more flexible in getting all folders and subfolders within that images path with one get request?

Comment: There is one thing though, when I try to access the route like this: http://localhost:8000/images/general/mini-logo.png, it does not call my imageCache function in the controller at all, although it is specified inside my get request, why is that? It simply returns the image. It seems to just request the resource from the image folder but not take into account my get route, why is that? Is it because public/image is the standard folder for resources? What do I do wrong here?

Comment: @Benny You can replace `/cache/images/{type}/{name}` with `'/cache/images/{any}` in your route, then in your controller you can access all the url segments. For your second question, you cannot create routes with the same name as a folder inside your public directory. So if you have `public/images` folder then a route to `/images` won't work since laravel considers the route as a resource route.

Comment: This sounds interesting, how would I be able to fetch like for example three paramters in this example? 'cache/images/{any} ??  How would the controller look like? Do I need to use request object here? How would I be able to fetch all three parameters with the cache/images/{any} route?